# Laravel many migrations issue

Tags: laravel, migration

10 people start new project with laravel. 
After for example 2,3 years there will be many migrations.

In case when new programmer joins the team he will setup development environment with code and database.

The problem is that if there are many migrations it will run too slow if there are thousand of migrations.

How to handle this?

Comment: Use a [migration generator](https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator) to generate a fresh batch of migrations. This has proven really useful for me. I should note there are some caveats, but you can just fork it and modify the package to meet your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes running 100s of migrations each time is going to become a headache. You'll want to create a snapshot of your database tables and make that your first migration.

For example lets say you have a blog with a `posts` and `users` table. For each table you're going to need a create table statement. If you're working with MySql to get your create table statement for your `users` table you would query:

`SHOW CREATE TABLE users`

Once you have your create table statements you can make a new migration which runs those queries and archive all your old migrations.

```
class CreateSnapshotTables extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        // Create users table
        DB::statement("
            CREATE TABLE `users` (
                `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                `password` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
                `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
                `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
                `remember_token` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
                `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
                `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
                `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
                UNIQUE KEY `users_email_unique` (`email`)
            );
        ");

        // Create posts table
        DB::statement("
            CREATE TABLE `posts` (
                `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,

                // ...etc.

                PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
                UNIQUE KEY `users_email_unique` (`email`)
            );
        ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good idea.
It will work.
There is one limitation that the migration should be made manually each time.

Some day maybe there will be automatic create db migration that scans all migrations and generate one migration, or with each new migration generates common migration be the last one.

For example if i create column username then change it to user then in the common migration there will be only "merged" changes with column "user".

One of the problem will be with irreversible migrations like removing column.